# Insert text box in a Google Docs document

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to make something like this text box that has a colored background (gray around my code in this example) in Google Docs.

```
I would like to put some gray box around my code
without any whitespacing - like this!
```

But it makes me a white spacing between every line. Is there any solution or plugin for this?

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Use a single cell table and set the cell background to gray.

## Instructions

1. Place the insertion cursor in the location of your document
2. Click on Table > Insert Table > 1 x 1
3. Click on Table > Table properties
   [image: Table properties]
4. Set the line size to 0
5. Set the background color of the cell
6. Click on the OK button.
7. Add the text to the table